# How to execute multiple bash commands in a root sub shell?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, root

I have a shell script that executes a series of terminal commands. What I would like to do is have these commands run through a root shell as they need root privileges.

**So far:**

Manually I would type :

```
sudo bash
```

into the terminal and a root shell would appear and I can execute all my commands.

**Problem:**

When I try to automate this process in my script, the root shell appears but none of my commands execute, once I close the root shell with `exit` the commands then execute.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: can you check your script's permissions?

Comment: To get the best or most relevant answers to your question, you should really add more details such as an excerpt of your script where sudo is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo` can run any command as *root*, not just a bash.
actually, it's suggested use is to run the commands you need rather than open a generic shell with root access.

so usually, you find something like the following in a script, giving super-user powers to only the commands that require them:

```
 $ cat myscript
 # cmd1 doesn't require supercow powers
 cmd1
 # but cmd2 and cmd3 do
 sudo cmd2
 sudo cmd3
 # cmd4 doesn't require supercow either
 cmd4
 $ ./myscript
 $
```

the nice part is, that `sudo` will cache the authorization for you: so if you have *just* entered the password correctly for *cmd2*, it won't ask you again for *cmd3*.

finally, if this is much to tedious you could also run the entire script via sudo (though again it's better to keep superuser privileges to a bare minimum, so i wouldn't exactly *recommend* this):

```
 $ cat myscript
 cmd1
 cmd2
 cmd3
 cmd4
 $ sudo ./myscript
 $
```

Comment: I see, this helps a lot. Although if its my script that opens the root shell, from that same script how would I pass commands into the root shell?

Comment: The cache is short-lived (5 minutes by default), which means `cmd3` may need reauthorization if `cmd2` takes longer. The clean approach is to configure `sudo` to allow the script runner to run certain (as specific as possible) commands without a password at all.

Comment: @SyntaxErr0r why do you want a `root shell` (and what exactly do you mean by it)? how is this different from my second suggestion (running a script as root?)

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways for a custom script to execute all your commands with superuser:

**Using [heredoc](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents):**

```
sudo -s <<EOF
#all root commands
#here
EOF
```

**Using `sudo` in every command:**

```
sudo cmd1
sudo cmd2
...
```

Compared to the heredoc method it has one disadvantage: If any command takes much time that the `sudo` session expires then the next sudo will ask for password again.

**running the script with sudo will run all of it's commands with superuser privilege.**

```
sudo /path/to/myscript
#all commands inside myscript gets sudo privilege
```

Comment: Cool indeed! This actually meets the requirement of the @syntaxerr0r that he need to open run the commands in the root shell.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding :

> When I try to automate this process in my script, the root shell
>   appears but none of my commands execute, once I close the root shell
>   with `exit` the commands then execute.

This is because doing `sudo bash` spawns a sub-shell which even though has the root privileges will be useless because the commands that you wish to execute are in the parent shell. So once you exit this `root shell` your successive commands run in the normal shell with normal privileges.

You could do it this way :

```
#!/bin/bash
function do_on_demand()
{
#The commands that you wish to execute as root goes here.
}
export -f do_on_demand
su root -c "do_on_demand"
```

Save as say `supercow`, do `chmod u+x supercow` and run it.

Doing this you could run a set of commands as root just by entering the
`root password` once.

**Edit:**

This may give you the root subshell as you wish :

```
su - -c "bash -c 'command1;command2'"
```

But a problem with this one is that the parent environment can't be used here, so be vigilant to give the full path to your scripts inside the bash commands.

Comment: this would allow *anybody* to run the script as root, which is a security issue.

Comment: @umläute : Even if we `setuid` to root permission will still be denied for commands like `chown`. So I changed the code completely,

Comment: This makes sense now. How would I execute commands through the sub shell ?

Comment: I am not sure why you would like to spawn a subshell here. You could group the commands in a function as I have done, export the function and feed it to the `su` command.

Comment: The advantage here is that, you don't have to type `sudo` multiple times.

Comment: @sjsam Is it possible to execute commands through the root subshell? Thats what I am aiming for.

Comment: @SyntaxErr0r: That would be tedious because `sudo` does not load a login shell environment before executing the command. See this [post](http://superuser.com/questions/709515/command-not-found-when-using-sudo)

Answer (score 0):

In my scripts, I just type `sudo` before any command that needs higher privilege. You can do `sudo su` as the first command in your script. When you run the script, it will ask for your password, and then complete as necessary.